# Helper Class missing in Symfony folder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, helper, web-development-server

I received FatalErrorException during Class Fetch. The Helper class is not in the Symfony folder. Attached is a screenshot of the problem and the file that calls for this helper class.

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Templating\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutUrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\Helper;

/**
 * LogoutUrlHelper provides generator functions for the logout URL.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Mikola <jmikola@gmail.com>
 */
class LogoutUrlHelper extends Helper
{
    private $generator;

    public function __construct(LogoutUrlGenerator $generator)
    {
        $this->generator = $generator;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the absolute logout path for the firewall.
     *
     * @param string|null $key The firewall key or null to use the current firewall key
     *
     * @return string The logout path
     */
    public function getLogoutPath($key)
    {
        return $this->generator->getLogoutPath($key, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH);
    }

    /**
     * Generates the absolute logout URL for the firewall.
     *
     * @param string|null $key The firewall key or null to use the current firewall key
     *
     * @return string The logout URL
     */
    public function getLogoutUrl($key)
    {
        return $this->generator->getLogoutUrl($key, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'logout_url';
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Error: During class fetch: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\Helper not found in /home/projetio/sites/gifton.projet.io/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Templating/Helper/LogoutUrlHelper.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /home/projetio/sites/gifton.projet.io/vendor/symfony/debug/DebugClassLoader.php(145): require('/home/projetio/...')
#1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\Bundle\\...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\Bundle\\...')
#3 /home/projetio/sites/gifton.projet.io/vendor/symfony/config/Resource/ClassExistenceResource.php(76): class_exists('Symfony\\Bundle\\...')
#4 /home/projetio/sites/gifton.projet.io/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(349): Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ClassExistenceResource->isFresh(0)
#5 /home/projetio/sites/gifton.projet.io/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/AutowirePass.php(312): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getReflectionClass('Symfo

in LogoutUrlHelper.php line 23
```

Comment: you sure installed with composer? (composer require symfony/templating) https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating.html#installation

Comment: @danigore yes, because everything else is OK. After I ran composer install, the var, vendor folders were generated

Comment: weirdly enough, the security bundle doesn't have symfony/templating as a dependency, which might be the reason ... can you please try `composer req symfony/templating`, and tell us whether something changed and if so, what it is? maybe this fixes the problem ... (related: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32342)

Comment: @Jakumi it worked in the end! it's an issue of the new php7.3.3 update, more details: [link](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/990) Thanks so much! :)